# How to get least amount between two date using Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need some logic for to get least amount between two date,my table like

```
create table #tmp(id int,deposit_id int,transaction_amount decimal(15,2),trn_date date,trn_type varchar(50));
insert into #tmp
select 1,101,15000,'2017-12-01','Receipt' -- 15000
union all
select 2,101,-5000,'2017-12-09','Payment' -- 10000
union all
select 3,101,6000,'2017-12-16','Receipt'   --16000
union all
select 4,101,-15000,'2017-12-20','Payment' -- 1000
union all
select 5,101,10000,'2017-12-22','Receipt' --11000
union all
select 5,101,-1000,'2017-12-22','Payment' --10000
union all
--- another deposit details
select 55,102,50000,'2017-12-04','Receipt' -- 50000
union all
select 56,102,5000,'2017-12-10','Receipt' -- 55000
```

I want least balance of each deposit between '2017-12-01' and '2017-12-31'.I cant get the logic for query to get this result because how can i check balance on each day for example on '2017-12-24'.Please give some tips.My desired result is

```
deposit_id   date   LeastAmt
    101  - '2017-12-20'  - 1000
    102  - '2017-12-04'  - 50000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question can be broken down into two parts.  First, we need to compute the rolling balance for the deposits table.  Then, we need to find the smallest balance for each account, within a given date range.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT d1.*,
        (SELECT SUM(d2.transaction_amount) FROM deposits d2
         WHERE d1.deposit_id  = d2.deposit_id AND d2.trn_date <= d1.trn_date) bal
    FROM deposits d1
)

SELECT
    id, deposit_id, transaction_amount, bal, trn_date, trn_type
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deposit_id ORDER BY bal) rn
    FROM cte
    WHERE trn_date BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Comment: sir i got error `The multi-part identifier "t2.transaction_amount" could not be bound.`

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ Typo `t2.transaction_amount` for `d2.transaction_amount`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate solution.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(id int,deposit_id int,transaction_amount decimal(15,2),trn_date date,trn_type varchar(50));

INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT 1,101,15000,'2017-12-01','Receipt' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,101,-5000,'2017-12-09','Payment' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,101,6000,'2017-12-16','Receipt'   
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,101,15000,'2017-12-20','Payment'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,101,10000,'2017-12-20','Receipt'
UNION ALL
SELECT 55,102,50000,'2017-12-04','Receipt'
UNION ALL
SELECT 56,102,5000,'2017-12-10','Receipt'

SELECT id, date, transaction_amount 
FROM (
    SELECT trn_date AS date, MIN(transaction_amount) AS LeastAmt
    FROM #tmp 
    WHERE trn_date BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
    GROUP BY trn_date
    ) A
    INNER JOIN #tmp ON trn_date = A.date AND transaction_amount = A.LeastAmt
ORDER BY id

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want the minimum transaction amount but rather then minimum balance.  You need to compute the rolling balance first.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh, that was unclear in the question imo.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY` on `balance` column like below:

Note: I am giving example of mysql, you can do same logic for your DB server.

```
SELECT balance 
FROM table_name 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN date1 AND date2 
ORDER BY balance limit 1;
```

If the value is dynamic like from union then you can use like:

```
SELECT balance 
FROM (
    SELECT bal1, date_created 
    FROM table1 
    UNION 
    SELECT bal2, date_created 
    FROM table2 
    UNION...
) AS A 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN date1 AND date2 
ORDER BY balance limit 1;
```

Comment: i don't have balance field,it is calculated dynamic field.

Comment: Dynamic based on what value? If you are doing union then also you can take out the particular value to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT deposit_id,trn_date,transaction_amount 
FROM tmp t 
WHERE trn_date >= '2017-12-01' AND 
    trn_date <= '2017-12-31' AND
    transaction_amount = (
        SELECT MIN(transaction_amount) 
        FROM tmp 
        WHERE t.deposit_id=deposit_id AND 
            trn_date >= '2017-12-01' AND 
            trn_date <= '2017-12-31')
```